# Joining 2 files to 1 in shell

Tags: linux, file, shell, unix, join

How do I join 2 files in shell, for example:

file1 -

```
server1          monthly      25
server2          monthly      24
server3          daily        21
server4          weekly       7
server5          weekly       7
```

file2 -

```
server1          monthly      5
server2          monthly      4
server3          daily        1
server4          weekly       2
```

Can you please help me to get get output like this:

```
server1          monthly      25     5
server2          monthly      24     4
server3          daily        21     1
server4          weekly       7      2
server5          weekly       7      0
```

Comment: server1 monthly      25
server2 monthly      24
server3  daily        21
server4  weekly       7
server5  weekly       7


server1 monthly      5
server2 monthly      4
server3  daily        1
server4  weekly       2


server1  monthly      25     5
server2  monthly      24     4
server3   daily        21     1
server4   weekly       7      2
server5   weekly       7      0

Answer (score 6):

This is a job for `join`:

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 2.3' file1 file2
server1 monthly 25 5
server2 monthly 24 4
server3 daily 21 1
server4 weekly 7 2
server5 weekly 7 0
```

Pipe to `column -t` for a nicely formatted table:

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 2.3' file file2 | column -t 
server1  monthly  25  5
server2  monthly  24  4
server3  daily    21  1
server4  weekly   7   2
server5  weekly   7   0
```

Use the redirection operator to store this to a newfile:

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 2.3' file file2 | column -t > newfile
```

Explanation:

```
-a            print unpairable lines from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is
              1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2

-e EMPTY      replace missing input fields with EMPTY

-o FORMAT     obey FORMAT while constructing output line
```

`-a` is used to display lines such as `server 5..` in `file1` where no such line is found in `file2` `-e 0` replaces any empty fields with `0` and `-o` is used to format the output where `1.1` means `file1 field 1` and `1.3` means `file1 field 3` ect.

Note: `join` does require the files to be sorted first *(which they are already in this case)* so is often combined with the use of the `sort` command.

Comment: This works for the sample data, but I suspect the actual process needs to join on both fields 1 and 2.  ("server1 monthly" should not be joined with "server1 daily"), so some preprocessing of the input would be necessary to use `join`.

Comment: I think in this case the sample data is the actual data, the `for example` was added in an edit by me. If this is actually the case *(which I doubt we will know)* then yes some pre/post-processing would be required.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2]=$3; next } { print $0, (a[$1,$2] ? a[$1,$2] : "0") | "column -t" }' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
server1  monthly  25  5
server2  monthly  24  4
server3  daily    21  1
server4  weekly   7   2
server5  weekly   7   0
```

Explanation:

> FNR==NR { ... } is a construct that is only true for the first file in the arguments list
>   So for the first file, we add columns one and two to an array assigning the third column as a value. 'next' simply forces awk to read the next line of input (thus, it skips processing the rest of the code)
>   Once awk has finished processing the first file, it will move onto the second file
>
> awk will now print out every line in the second file. Tacked onto the end of this print statement is an operator called a ternary operator and this statement is in the form: ( x ? a : b )
>    It simply means: if (x) then (a) else (b). I could have written:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2]=$3; next } { if (a[$1,$2]!=0) print $0, a[$1,$2]; else print $0, "0" }' file2 file1 | column -t
```

...but ternaries are sexy.

Comment: Many Thanks..Awk works well for me..but I am trying to understand the logic here

Comment: @user1899817 `awk` is a great tool and lets you do powerful stuff however `join` was written for this exact purpose, you have `--help` and `man` pages for reference and is definitely the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Much Sudo_O -Join is well explainable and it also helps me but I am still tyring to understand the logic with awk